# How to properly type event handler in wrapped addEventListener call in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, addeventlistener, typescript-typings

I'm trying to write an abstraction layer on the `addEventListener` method, but am running into a typing issue. In the minimal reproduction below;

```js
function addEventListener<T extends EventTarget>(
  element: T,
  type: string,
  handler: EventListener
) {
  element.addEventListener(type, handler);
}

addEventListener<Window>(window, "mousedown", (event: MouseEvent) => {
  console.log(event.pageX);
});
```

TypeScript complains that the parameter type is incompatible with MouseEvent:

```
Argument of type '(event: MouseEvent) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventListener'.
  Types of parameters 'event' and 'evt' are incompatible.
    Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'MouseEvent': altKey, button, buttons, clientX, and 20 more.
```

I know that the following (basic) event listener:

```js
window.addEventListener('mousedown', (event: MouseEvent) => {
  console.log(event.pageX);
});
```

works just fine, so I'm assuming something is wrong in typing the `handler` parameter as `EventListener`, but I can't figure out what it should be.. Most answers I came across seem specific to React, which is not relevant in my case.

Above codesnippet on: [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=19&pc=1#code/PTAEHUHsCcGsGcBcBYAUAdwJYDsAml0A6AQ11wFEA3AU2wBcAZTeO266ACgHIBbSAV3jV86bFwA0oDtRr1EoALIChVWnQCUoALwA+UAG80oUAGNI2eJAA21QlcgBzabLqEADsQfUAGuoDcaAC+-mhoIAC0kVHRMbFx8QmJSfGhqCCgACKQ1PCg2JB0oOgwsCioAGb82CZ0mOagpBQuTCxs0AA8ACqg1AAerHi5qvSdxNBedDocRj02PGryneIzdACebtTyLNA4DsuoxgAWxHg20PLDjMwD7Giahgez1PP0JGSXLTecaxuSx6fsEKoQKpRofa5tdrgHAiKZYPAESQAIj4gmEBGwSMkzgWimU1Euml0BhmZgs1ls9icMjU7k8PiBwQCqDQQA) | [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-vdwes?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that your `addEventListener()` typing has no idea how the `type` parameter relates to the subtype of `Event` that `handler` should accept.  In the TypeScript standard library file [`lib.dom.d.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.7.5/lib/lib.dom.d.ts), individual `EventTarget` types are given a very specific mapping from `type` to `handler`.  For example, the `Window` interface's signature for its `addEventListener` method [looks like this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.7.5/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L18657):

```
addEventListener<K extends keyof WindowEventMap>(
  type: K, 
  listener: (this: Window, ev: WindowEventMap[K]) => any, 
  options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions
): void;
```

where `WindowEventMap` is [defined here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.7.5/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L18434-L18532) as a large mapping between `type` names and `Event` type.  For the `mousedown` key specifically, the [property value type is `MouseEvent`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.7.5/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L18474).  Thus when you call

```
window.addEventListener('mousedown', (event: MouseEvent) => {
  console.log(event.pageX);
});
```

everything works because `K` is inferred to be `"mousedown"` and thus the `handler` parameter expects a `MouseEvent`.

---

Without that sort of mapping information, the typings tend to look like `type` is `string` and `listener` is `(event: Event)=>void`.  But, as you've seen, you can't simply pass a `(event: MouseEvent)=>void` to a parameter expecting a `(event: Event)=>void`, because it's not safe in general to do this.  If you give me a function that only accepts `MouseEvent`s, I can't use it as a function that accepts all `Event`s.  If I try, and the function you give me accesses something like the `pageX` property, I might get a runtime error.

This sort of restriction on function arguments was added in TypeScript 2.6 as a [`--strictFunctionTypes` compiler option](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types).  If you turn that compiler option off your error should disappear, but I don't recommend you do that.

Instead, if you want to loosen the typing just for your `addEventListener` function, you could make it generic in the `Event` subtype, like this:

```
function addEventListener<T extends EventTarget, E extends Event>(
  element: T, type: string, handler: (this: T, evt: E) => void) {
  element.addEventListener(type, handler as (evt: Event) => void);
}
```

Then your code will compile:

```
addEventListener(window, "mousedown", (event: MouseEvent) => {
  console.log(event.pageX);
});
```

But remember: this typing is too loose to catch errors, such as this:

```
addEventListener(document.createElement("div"), "oopsie",
  (event: FocusNavigationEvent) => { console.log(event.originLeft); }
);
```

If you were to try that directly on an `HTMLDivElement` you'd get an error:

```
document.createElement("div").addEventListener("oopsie",
  (event: FocusNavigationEvent) => { console.log(event.originLeft); }
); // error! oopsie is not acceptable
```

Which wouldn't be resolved until you fixed both the `type` parameter

```
document.createElement("div").addEventListener("blur",
  (event: FocusNavigationEvent) => { console.log(event.originLeft); }
); // error! FocusNavigationEvent is not a FocusEvent
```

And used the matching `Event` subtype

```
document.createElement("div").addEventListener("blur",
  (event: FocusEvent) => { console.log(event.relatedTarget); }
); // okay now
```

---

So, that's about as far as I can go here.  You could *try* to make an enormous mapping from all known `EventTarget` types to all the correct `type` parameters for each target, and then to all the correct `Event` subtypes for each `EventTarget`/`type` pair, and have a single generic `addEventListener` function that works... but it would be comparable in size to the `lib.dom.d.ts` file, and I'm not inclined to spend too much more time on this.  If you need type safety you would probably be better off not using this particular abstraction.  Otherwise, if you're okay with the compiler missing some mismatches, then the above typing could be a way to go.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEA5A9gFwOoEtgBM0B3JAbwFgAoKpJIvQogOhH3wFEA3CYDAGRxQMPCACcAFAHIwaAK5QIjYJIA0ScRG68AXEgCychVx4YAlEgC8APjI1aSeGmBQ0AGwhNXaAOYatGJjhvCAANUwBuOwBfCKo7ADNZYHgMHCckVg5-ASERUQAeABUkCAAPYQIoJGNeQpBRYIw1dhLynnwqmowrcTtaCHdIHSRCtQwATxgIXSFRPG81AAsQAndRXXEMRcFdUZLODF12c2skTjQcfHMKSnsSwZMWNi6cirFNyYgllfw1jKq-Idqv4TjZzpdYrckFE4tQoZkXoI3hJ6ARiGoAEQyeSKYjADFqPwmXQGHFdUG2KG0RzONweLy+TSPIKhSG0GKROG0BHZJF5cSEeCyIYBeCiCAgYTsB68cQY-A4TgY0yYtBoGBQHAQAl9dRM4YAMTQQqgKBAnBw3klaWA5MsNlIDicLncnh8RN4TDQc28eD4EHiZnC0LskLsguFjzFEqlMowcoVStMTyyJle-Ixao1Wp1VL1-l0RpNZotVtSTjtp0dNJd9Pd+oC3stfoDQZDUIiSAA9F2SqJRN6AIRILOa5CCJDATAZeCIGAYEAAI3csNoEZFTGjkog0ogIoTiuVKcRuWA7wxy9kolzdw9QKL8hLlutFZB9rITtproZd69PpbgadjCHbBj2fYDqIw4Pqa5rPuWtr+EgE5ThgGRINBXSrkg65RuK267vu8qHsmPJpnyZ4SBerhXje9h3oWxryJWDqfrWbqMv4TDiq4274HUDQQG2wG0J2YFoAA1iA4yTsQsJUMBQA)

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution that mostly works. It requires listing all `EventMap` types but after that it should catch all errors.

```js
// List all `EventMap` types here.
type DOMEventMapDefinitions = [
  [HTMLElement, HTMLElementEventMap],
  [Document, DocumentEventMap],
  [Window, WindowEventMap],
  [FileReader, FileReaderEventMap],
  [Element, ElementEventMap],
  [Animation, AnimationEventMap],
  [EventSource, EventSourceEventMap],
  [AbortSignal, AbortSignalEventMap],
  [AbstractWorker, AbstractWorkerEventMap]
  // ...
];
type DOMEventSubscriber = DOMEventMapDefinitions[number][0];

type MapDefinitionToEventMap<D extends { [K: number]: any[] }, T> = { [K in keyof D]: D[K] extends any[] ? (T extends D[K][0] ? D[K][1] : never) : never };
type GetDOMEventMaps<T extends DOMEventSubscriber> = MapDefinitionToEventMap<DOMEventMapDefinitions, T>;

type MapEventMapsToKeys<D extends { [K: number]: any }> = { [K in keyof D]: D[K] extends never ? never : keyof D[K] };
type MapEventMapsToEvent<D extends { [K: number]: any }, T extends PropertyKey> = { [K in keyof D]: D[K] extends never ? never : (T extends keyof D[K] ? D[K][T] : never) };

// Works for all types listed in `DOMEventMapDefinitions` and any types that are assingable to those types.
function customAddEventListener<T extends DOMEventSubscriber, K extends MapEventMapsToKeys<GetDOMEventMaps<T>>[number] & string>(
  element: T,
  type: K,
  handler: (this: T, ev: (MapEventMapsToEvent<GetDOMEventMaps<T>, K>[number])) => any
) {
  element.addEventListener(type, handler as any);
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Examples:


window.addEventListener('mousedown', (event: MouseEvent) => {
  console.log(event.pageX);
});

customAddEventListener(window, "mousedown", (event: MouseEvent) => {
  console.log(event.pageX);
});


document.createElement("div").addEventListener("oopsie",
  (event: FocusNavigationEvent) => { console.log(event.originLeft); }
); // error! oopsie is not acceptable

customAddEventListener(document.createElement("div"), "oopsie",
  (event: FocusNavigationEvent) => { console.log(event.originLeft); }
); // error! Argument of type '"oopsie"' is not assignable ...


document.createElement("div").addEventListener("blur",
  (event: FocusNavigationEvent) => { console.log(event.originLeft); }
); // error! FocusNavigationEvent is not a FocusEvent

customAddEventListener(document.createElement("div"), "blur",
  (event: FocusNavigationEvent) => { console.log(event.originLeft); }
); // error! 'FocusEvent' is not assignable to type 'FocusNavigationEvent'


document.createElement("div").addEventListener("blur",
  (event: FocusEvent) => { console.log(event.relatedTarget); }
); // okay now

customAddEventListener(document.createElement("div"), "blur",
  (event: FocusEvent) => { console.log(event.relatedTarget); }
); // okay now
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKA9GAEAyCWDOAXSBDANmyADAogNwFMA7RAWRQActJEBPCg+SACwICcCA6UOhyAEQDypfMTKV+BAGawisRLAD2RJgF5IAbVCRNACQAqpaDjQEAtmIA0kA0ZPmxokuQoBdS9s39FAYwCuFiTW3v6BiE7ibh4gOhoA6rIAJooA7tYJRMkpES7unhoAYrCmAEoEKIns1kWl5ZVsOZR5MZr2YdZtjoTOTdGxAIJyZigKytaDsMOjRI1R+REAyop+bD4EHd2ISytrs80DAEaKbFuwAOZE6ONHJwvnl2h7fZr9B0hsKD6IcccA1lWQV7vT7fP7sPaeCCQTgw0CuADcPHoBAEwkWfjePjYsAO7Eg6iEIk2LkkMjk03gGiIAVxbFcGgADAjQEi+CTpLJ5EoiPpFLMADz8SAEAAeiGIiSYAG9NABpABckGpZlprkVKCItA0rkgAF9rPoAHz4yAyjSyyCySD-WiKKQCNUCc060XizJMDVanUAfkgAAp9MKxRKmPxnYyfU7ZfSAIw6xVEAiENgASkgCaTeN1iJAvBRAHECIhCbN4PzA66Q6iiWIFhj4Ficexjep2WSucpeQKS8SJBzydz4AbDTnWSiXKXebKCLQy0LK+7TXKEzT2I7PXqW0vzZaiNaZ3aHYqw9Gg27JUrM2xIL7E8n0-vbfaTzrs2PIBPexR4F3NoKz1WZoKkqq50uqmp6gaAGLgACmwigMCctDTrQW5Abuj6HvwjovtBF53nit5Xg+AZ4UwNpYc6N5RvS+jxpeyZpm+ICgFCPxsL8TBSMcqAYDQyJMGgCDiokGFYD2YhtpyFLUBqokbnmTCIMwIyoBwqDwPAshnCgBymDQig0MwijwCiincCAUh+EQXzcpA-hIIoZj9IkiQRHASDEOw5ZkdW6KYtitLWBaC4Xp+kmUD+igoWWhbFmiX5lkahpUqBOoAGSQO82mGn6ngEKYYSKvozx5oqsrPCpmSmGwip+spCDFdYSZ1eFPTfr+Yj8nFEntUlhrBSlyqqimaaqManqgGmUr5YVYicBUbmbB5brsPVyLWFViQ1RpqCaimOa6iyLHgGAAC0F2XVd103bdd33Q9j13axUA4CKKBmBQpjwPKx2gCkSSpAtrnucJXlsH6ADkZjLKZWREJD1h+pmJCKqQsMEBEY3GjNLQ+Mo8CKKYnBoIoZzI5snAUCgZwEAAGgdoC6ozJ0OYgTkuUtYgreDfoA5kqTWAARDDfhw6kRBC0jKOIGjGNY-iOOePjKhE1wpPkzLVM0-TLPM6OJ3JKE81YuU4qdCQfpC4ksB4ELKbA1zJA84mENC4oCFaQQUueBTYiKgUvhiwAcigeDnCM3IK+NS4q4TxMa37JCcMc5yyNA0iIAdepTfCkBQuw8FsAAhJAHvfrAKIIEqijIJ8awUIgummMdbMcyDy1g67fpGwEJscCMmNzZb1u2-bwvl17PstEnsuQIHDmh+HOnTNHOP2QTask2Ts8p9iZzp5n2dHSA2cF2wRel-0bBnH3JBl-aeaQJD7ue5XQuQ5aTBELXGlaRczcUQwgssdXuYROCm0HhbRAVsbZ2wdotUGnlu5Cz0isaeOhZ4ByDvAJeEdV6bGxrHTeCcd5a1TgfIgGcpBZzzifM+UBC7HFLgvEOYd8FR02F-Gudd544IiK3MW7NnId25l3NaYD+5myHg4EecDx6QFQWgdBzwsF8MXuwlenCxBEJlHHLeidyH70PjQ4+ud86MIvsw5+rD4ARE-tXH+ddNL3EAQZfifBIa2LwVo5Q9i-ogEkcnSB5th4wNHvAx2SDVpuzQWwDB-oZbYIcmvYhqtSGa0phwNAg9Ej6BQDfIsZjT55yhIoX4KBaA1xSIIxyIinaIBdhIoO4CQkyLCLAseKZhZxISWo2xqS9EkPVmQrJBVcn5MKbQnOJSLFlwqVUn+NSQBAA)

[Playground Link with more (all?) EventMap types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKA9GAEAyCWDOAXSBDANmyADAogNwFMA7RAWRQActJEBPCg+SACwICcCA6UOhyAEQDypfMTKV+BAGawisRLAD2RJgF5IAbVCRNAQQBGitogDKsAOZF0AGkgGjpi1bSiS5CgF1r2vfqRsUAGNEAHUjAGt2WwN-INCI9ldxT28QHQ1dOQBbFAVlaOzcpSIk9y8fDIoKNFhAouUAYSDWaKqauryiJsDWUspytL0AVwATJRMeghGhtCmTRSG2QIIAOUURgmjR8cnp2ZH5xeW1jb6Uit1txTC2cNnEE827K5u7ggf1gjOB9IAhFHgBEuY0UDWUiAIAA9ELZ-oDgUowSQoYhvqk-mxFCgRnUkA1mCgiEQCGhYZjsbjEPjCcSXIQ3P10Zp+IpAkMsmJbCy2RySGiKtz2WJMiMcLNeaj6YgABKEkazNjwLmsoUkEViggSpKyojy9jwfmDDQaiW2E1iQ3pJKHJZPa0LW2WzQAMVgswASgRsVFIK6PV6NmwnRoAOJoRT6dDauUKpWQMMRqNSnV6xXB6UAFVI0F+61o5pItkz2dzI3z4otUrKTI0xegBZhkDrDfTWegzoCHJM7wbRbbHZQXZ7Fb5VcZFTr5DYAEchgQviPG5OUDO5wvNZWxNWJ23SFNYChe03d-vD4vgwBJfi-fi5FCRwG2K83u8Pr5j85G5+CBhEa+e2dGEbb9f3-AhAKQS8wIg4DoLnSCPx+TRnwzAIVDiYon2vVDCXgDDlGDUgTAvIgKCGMh3mYdYkQhaFbCIkiyIoxAqJGGiUUI09JDwWpGHoriCB45YDUQms9zGFAAGkCFobt4HgTDIHEg9pNkxgFII0SKmUlAAEU5zYWg4CQfiJP09gjIQSUt3HI0dJtZZTIPBz3xsz90nsxAOEHJyUBMLyvSyTiJP87yshwwJwl80LAoi8JOPklBzAIAAFBx+MS5K0uMYM1gUGQOkUvLYAK+oSi0o1BCkKQamJBFQXBFFbCqmrZCBK52OhYMUpQWgJQA+DGx6vqxAGoDuvYKQjByIhHMgFLJumwllgmtgsgQDSiH83IhjjBa1o24ptsQXbg3dDMGn4LNnW7XUfXOy7rtuwMzou29EBQakiRJWwHvez6CW+uk3KQjQ-sQNB4BwlQKHSyBwch6H4FhnKKvScGsikZ77rexBMexoM0c0B6L2WENclYDg2F+i7SYIcmWPYRIibB2nliRlHGxJ9m0ORhxXoaBb2CRYlgkUh6hbYEWCDFzSQZrB6JkQCgObhxXghV3nOYFkxjAoEwNihrW1Yu3XlYNxhVdR+WKhMAA1EMj3tx3zxZ53nadh2Pddm2jQmDhiEENhYDEMrbH9+ciCDkOSDK4N-dgChEBSzFhPgIxHnDwJg6TlPWXUjPPnj9ghIIV4fW7NhS-LwnffSSvq4SKXwRQNrqcgBveJrmjW+JWuGXczRO+WGvPXMKyAk6cOS67pux4nuO3YdZZfiGaqK+XghV-X-vklBlzt6kdhjMbA+16PtgT-jhgZeYT1AkUSx5EUkwb56e-H7kTpr-nHoTFoEgrAFJxlfr-Zg-9AGMAQD-W+EDGbAIAKqIAhGhOaoDYEAPgQgJBKDlquQHqDDMKI4q2CIdCOKwYyGIDig0OcpDiEBEirQ-Be8axULiifeh5DGHhCvizEIBB9DzEiu8WwAihGskiNZAhNYQiyBGIoAA7mI+RSjgxyN1Go5MMZ9QqM0Yo6MupYzqKbmIpuwYAAa2ZpTIIoGNEykArHQBscrex0jWEVCcS4ux4FBpJAzCuZKjYvG2Lcf4wJPYKoeAANw8HoAQAQwhrRDD8NnWA+h2CQHUEIEQH5JAyC-sUeAGgiDsgyWwDwGgAAMMTQBxL4O4fJshn7KAzIoM4AAefgkAUTEBGEwAA3poSSAAuSApSsjlI8GMwktANAeEgAAX1IQAPiyZAIZGhJKQFkJASItBFBSAENMgQWyFm9N1EwWZ8zIAAH5IAAAoMw9OhH0pg-AznVIWfcj5klKkAEYFljOJIQNgABKSAwLBKZMWbEkAvAEkhneDks48AOnPIuf0xJuSxAmBSfANJ5S1nqEadIZpnQ2mdJRXkslhTlBxgzCsuF9SEnuFRW01SaLumYsGcM4FZT2AnNmUs4lGzhk7KIHsmShzjljN+ec15lzxnQrYHc5VoLIVSoOUc+VSy4UIqUpQdl7SpRdJeRCJVmzRnjIFRUmZRBaBLNIeat581MQMGMLQVSoqrUSq1TK-gJzdU8vVZk+5ILMljKeS6pV+yA1nLVfKjQGYgWhvBXqup4AoCvCYFNVV6BMAIqYDUJAUw-VYGpW5JpdKVDUDlKgB1NB4lMBYrkVAHBUDyVkOYe8swaCKBoFRQETaGDwG4CAKQQxZqdEgGyJAigsi6BGKKKUJ9iDsHRTGrFlaSB4tScHcpthtkhrZR+KGihOUdKRYgHdyQ0WMpWSU21CyABkkB-DdpWQ8nwJINwkDGRmJkCKxmSSZIDVMUaWIIAA7YQSUbT1uXPUkK9yKklnvRSso9j6JlTLBRC1QazZmgAhQMn9i5ODYhXWINdfcHkItsOBhUnaG20DBXCxZmbQAQAALS8b4-xgTgmhPCZE6JsTwmuNQBwJCQc1RGAjM4yARRqjFEUeXUkGj7AHkAHIsgLEBAoxRRBtO2AedC-9Sl9MsPw2s0jgwH4qEULMTg4ZzBmalJwCgSUCAWLY6ARZfmQCgDnYgBdS6qMkE02wB5yn9G2AAER6d2lMJRRB4umfM4gMZpArNJBsxsnwDn07Odc+5sQnnvO+fY4FzNCieTlezl6CEDYHnxbGHgeLYK1MRcQFF1rihFAUAUgQdLPgysWedCqeAKwUA8R7d-KU+WhlFac1wUrmXOBGAsLIaA0hEBsaWcR6JkAIA9LYJiNgABCSAA2hshx2UwIgihkBBGWEnXtBBM0hbC+p1dVl13Rbq6qRAnBGu5HXBKVr7XOsJdu8N0bgxxtZd9FNmbc3F5iCW7O+lq2XOPyR5t4O48iC7akPt47HGQAHdO+wC713dBsHMMDm7RyDXafi3DkO8XtMPfGc9ztClLAfcgJwUXimgcSlB95Zri4oewA611yjGn-u0fi-oNAiwEc6CR2Mybc60cWAxyQLHK2Sv4421t4npPyeHap8dmn52jDXb17tA383ihJF509l7KO51JC+7tULi7fvUZV1piXDXpcQ7EHLhXCX1ea6ZDr33rvZuG4W5jrJtnseObN25i3ROdt7YO5T6nUBadO8gNpl3IkxA84QHzl7Xahfq4SaFkdCTq+o7T+7uWJBtPi5VJLsHMu-2IFj517ryvS2q4T2wLXjzMu66m3lrPYrTdrfNx5jgaBwcjACYz94JejsnagIocIvU+eKID-O4PPW+sR5IFLpr0eSAT7BfHjX8+k9L5T7X43a+y2OOeeBOO+e+B+QSx+dup+N2F+jqT21+IAQAA)

[Playground Link with some optimizations for compile times](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKA9GAEAyCWDOAXSBDANmyADAogNwFMA7RAWRQActJEBPCg+SACwICcCA6UOhyAEQDypfMTKV+BAGawisRLAD2RJgF5IAbVCRNAQQBGitogDKsAOZF0AGkgGjpi1bSiS5CgF1r2vfqRsUAGNEAHUjAGt2WwN-INCI9ldxT28QHQ1dOQBbFAVlaOzcpSIk9y8fDIoKNFhAouUAYSDWaKqauryiJsDWUspytL0AVwATJRMeghGhtCmTRSG2QIIAOUURgmjR8cnp2ZH5xeW1jb6Uit1txTC2cNnEE827K5u7ggf1gjOB9IAhFHgBEuY0UDWUiAIAA9ELZ-oDgUowSQoYhvqk-mxFCgRnUkA1mCgiEQCGhYZjsbjEPjCcSXIQ3P10Zp+IpAkMsmJbCy2RySGiKtz2WJMiMcLNeaj6YgABKEkazNjwLmsoUkEViggSpKyojy9jwfmDDQaiW2E1iQ3pJKHJZPa0LW2WzQAMVgswASgRsVFIK6PV6NmwnRoAOJoRT6dDauUKpWQMMRqNSnV6xXB6UAFVI0F+61o5pItkz2dzI3z4otUrKTI0xegBZhkDrDfTWegzoCHJM7wbRbbHZQXZ7Fb5VcZFTr5DYAEchgQviPG5OUDO5wvNZWxNWJ23SFNYChe03d-vD4vgwBJfi-fi5FCRwG2K83u8Pr5j85G5+CBhEa+e2dGEbb9f3-AhAKQS8wIg4DoLnSCPx+TRnwzAIVDiYon2vVDCXgDDlGDUgTAvIgKCGMh3mYdYkQhaFbCIkiyIoxAqJGGiUUI09JDwWpGHoriCB45YDUQms9zGFAAGkCFobt4HgTDIHEg9pNkxgFII0SKmUlAAEU5zYWg4CQfiJP09gjIQSUt3HI0dJtZZTIPBz3xsz90nsxAOEHJyUBMLyvSyTiJP87yshwwJwl80LAoi8JOPklBzAIAAFBx+MS5K0uMYM1gUGQOkUvLYAK+oSi0o1BCkKQamJBFQXBFFbCqmrZCBK52OhYMUpQWgJQA+DGx6vqxAGoDuvYKQjByIhHMgFLJumwllgmtgsgQDSiH83IhjjBa1o24ptsQXbg3dDMGn4LNnW7XUfXOy7rtuwMzou29EBQakiRJWwHvez6CW+uk3KQjQ-sQNB4BwlQKHSyBwch6H4FhnKKvScGsikZ77rexBMexoM0c0B6L2WENclYDg2F+i7SYIcmWPYRIibB2nliRlHGxJ9m0ORhxXoaBb2CRYlgkUh6hbYEWCDFzSQZrB6JkQCgObhxXghV3nOYFkxjAoEwNihrW1Yu3XlYNxhVdR+WKhMAA1EMj3tx3zxZ53nadh2Pddm2jQmDhiEENhYDEMrbH9+ciCDkOSDK4N-dgChEBSzFhPgIxHnDwJg6TlPWXUjPPnj9ghIIV4fW7NhS-LwnffSSvq4SKXwRQNrqcgBveJrmjW+JWuGXczRO+WGvPXMKyAk6cOS67pux4nuO3YdZZfiGaqK+XghV-X-vklBlzt6kdhjMbA+16PtgT-jhgZeYT1AkUSx5EUkwb56e-H7kTpr-nHoTFoEgrAFJxlfr-Zg-9AGMAQD-W+EDGbAIAKqIAhGhOaoDYEAPgQgJBKDlquQHqDDMKI4q2CIdCOKwYyGIDig0OcpDiEBEirQ-Be8axULiifeh5DGHhCvizEIBB9DzEiu8WwAihGskiNZAhNYQiyBGIoAA7mI+RSjgxyN1Go5MMZ9QqM0Yo6MupYzqKbmIpuwYAAa2ZpTIIoGNEykArHQBscrex0jWEVCcS4ux4FBpJAzCuZKjYvG2Lcf4wJPYKoeAANygB4PQAgSkJDSFkM-ZQGZFBnAADz8FIQAPkgOoAA3poSSkBZCQEiLQRQUgBAeAAFwCA0JJDwkAUTEBGEwDQhJaC2B6a0gA-JAAAFBmNp0IOlMH4M0jwGgAAMgymktI0AARlaY04khA2AAEpIAbMEuwSAABfWJIBeCJJDO8IQIgPzwCyRmAp6h3CSBkF-YoGTsnXLOC81JnQ4wPNOfEvg7gzhQ0UKpO5-BHmQBKc08pRBKkyRqXUxp0yWnjIhLqJgmzDlDJxWwPZiLqm1LRa0k5QLEkgtuR8qUOTSEYsmfNTEDBjC0FUtC2FZSKlVORfwBpSzWntKxZAfFkA8UHIJY00ZDLhU8pJTMsVAqNAZnWSKiVkBdnkpAKACAkBXhMCmgS9AmBzlMBqEgKY8LsBfI-D8t5yh4DUDlKgIgtAaAJKYCxXIqAOCoHkrIcw95Zg0EUDQKigJ3UMHgNwEAUghizU6JANkSBFBZF0CMUUUoT7EHYPcmVnTIDhLYEE2wZShUFqpW5MFEKsmkDyRoIg7J9DsFaQAMkgP4AN9F81MEuYgG1Vb7l5LycMnwJINwkEaRmJk5zGmSSZIDVMUqWIICnbYQSUrK0DzBUkWtpb62NqyM2tgHhtm7NUAUnpoBdlFLHYuTg2JM1iGzX3YZ5zbCLoVH6l1tBtmnKOXE7V4AwAAFowPgYg5BqD0GYOwbg-BmDOqoA4EhIOaojB6mAdAIo1RiiH0ZqSC+9gwyADkWQFiAgUYoogJHbDDIOZOpSFGWHnoKbewYD8VCKFmJwcM5h6NSk4BQJKBALF-tAEc8TQHk2IFTemp9JAiNsGGTh-RtgABE5HdpTCUUQdTdGGOIEaaQZjSRWMwp8Jx9OPG+MCbEEJkTYn-1ScAwonk9ns5eghA2YZ6mxh4HU9s-DCnEBKd84oRQFAFIEH0z4OzjHnQqngCsFAPFA3fylOZkpVnuNcFs4ZzgRgLCyGgNIRAf7jnXuiZAXV7BMRsAAISQAi1FkO5TsWKGQEEZYScg0EEAzJuTBGs1WRzcptzqpECcE87kdcEpfP+cCxplr0XYuDHi0Z30SWUtpcXmILLSaHW5d44-DbhXg7jyIKVqQ5XqsAZABV2rbB6tNd0MWybzXannMgCR9TK2Q7qZI+1kVnW-UKUsH1yAnBodYZABNiU03vLecXAt2AAWguPsI6N196n9BoEWGtnQG3GmJeTTtiwe2SAHZyzZ07BWiuXeu7dyrD3qtPZe1tsnqWKcZbEMDogoOUCc9OlKAbu1ZNpuG8+7HxH4ceaR3NsQqP0cabxwTpkxPhfJe5+l4oZnClscO1x2n-H6cXZK2Vir93HtQDq0YJrJHSci7EEDhAIOuv+oh3jxJsnI2JMd9tnXlPEAkdh3LkgiOvOK5IMrwLwWscWpx2rtghORmGZJ0l-XF6YVG+s3lungmOBoFmyMAJxb3hW6qzVqAihwi9RB4osXKbJchbC+HqbM3kcTsQLH7Zqv8cp41+nrXWfDc0-z6bwvJIS9l6CZX1n1fmt17dQLxvIAgA)