# Forward handler argument types in generic helper for addEventListener

Tags: typescript

How can I type this properly in TypeScript such that `ev` is inferred?

```js
type Unsubscribe = () => void;

function subscribeEvent<
  Target extends {
    addEventListener(...args: AddArgs): void
    removeEventListener(...args: RemoveArgs): void
  },
  AddArgs extends any[],
  RemoveArgs extends any[]
>(target: Target, ...args: AddArgs & RemoveArgs): Unsubscribe {
  target.addEventListener(...args);
  return () => {
    target.removeEventListener(...args);
  };
}

window.addEventListener('storage', ev => console.log(ev.storageArea));

// error: Parameter 'ev' implicitly has an 'any' type.(7006)
subscribeEvent(window, 'storage', ev => console.log(ev.storageArea));
```

Currently `ev` for `addEventListener` is inferred to `StorageEvent` but for my helper TypeScript can't figure it out and warns it implicitly has any type.

Also there is no autocomplete on first argument (type).

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgZwK4CMEGMBOBLF0C8UAFAJRT4B8UAbgPbYAmA3ALABQ7AZknOsNrThRkaLLggBRahDjAAPOyhQAKgENMAcwjAoEAB7AZDBFADeipVFUMGUmcAAy2BIbgRMRAHTf1GhAC4oAEEbIM0EEkC6RgslTAgAW1ppO1knFxl3Lx9wwIAlROSIML9ImnoGCwBfABoLEIYSk31XYys4EABtAF06tiUCpOkm3QMjE1UOnvYKImBfbUC1TW0aqG9PXwDg0PCoADIoQaKmsvgRDBw8Mwt5leBNm1THZ1csja2SVn6oeOAkTBCUjkKjmH5KO5aB7xIaSaRpV6ZDwfcJfarfKrsdgAd2wcAYtGxj1s8JeGTcHgA5C5aJhVFpKWsINQQVB0IIELQADYQTxc2gaIjMzw0ulaMIQVQkNEcNgXMR4Z5EXH4wlranAWn0iCM3Qsyhsjnc3n8wXC0XaiVSmVAA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really do it because you would need to get each overload on `window` (or whatever other target is passed) and then extract the arguments but because of [this TS limitation](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32164) you can't do it reliably. The hacky workarounds there don't work here because, on a large number of overloads, it hits some type of instantiation limit.

It can only really be done if the target is known. So here's one that works only for `window`. You could perhaps overload it with other signatures for other targets you need to support, but that'd be ugly.

```
function subscribeEvent<K extends keyof WindowEventMap>(
  target: typeof window,
  type: K,
  cb: (this: Window, ev: WindowEventMap[K]) => any
): Unsubscribe {
  target.addEventListener(type, cb);
  return () => {
    target.removeEventListener(type, cb);
  };
}
```

If you really want to take the idea forward of mapping types for every possible event see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62010854/1086398.